# I deleted my local directory in tf. How to re-get it?

Tags: tfs

I am on linux, command line tf.

I delete my local directory. Now the tf get does not retrieve the files -

How do I get it back from tfs???

Comment: Do you mean you deleted it from the repo or from your actual filesystem?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the following command:

```
tf get /force
```

You could also use `/all`. But I prefer `/force` to resync a working copy with the server, just so that nothing is missed.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx7sdeyf%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> **/all**
>   Forces all files to be retrieved, not just those that are
>   out-of-date.
>
> **/overwrite**
>   Overwrites writable files that are not checked out.
>
> **/force**
>   Implies **/all** and **/overwrite**.